# primefaces change editor for one column in datatable based on the selection in another column

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I have a requirement for an editable datatable that has a single column, lets say brand, that when set to "Other" will replace the editor in the next column, model -  with an inputText rather than a selectOne. If any particular car brand is selected then the list of models for that brand is displayed. If "Other" is chosen then they can type in a model in an input text field. I can't seem to get the mechanics of this to work in primefaces using various combinations of rendered and events. Is this sort of inline switching of editing components based on the data in the row possible?  I've built a simple example using the primefaces datatable demo for cars (and adding a field Model) to illustrate what I am attempting.

Page snippet

```
            <p:dataTable id="cars1" var="car" value="#{dtEditView.cars1}"
            editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <f:facet name="header">
                  Row Editing
            </f:facet>

            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{dtEditView.onRowEdit}"
                update="cars1" />
            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{dtEditView.onRowCancel}"
                update="cars1" />

            <p:column headerText="Id">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{car.id}" style="width:100%" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Year">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{car.year}" style="width:100%" label="Year" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Brand">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.brand}" style="width:100%">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{dtEditView.brands}" var="man"
                                itemLabel="#{man}" itemValue="#{man}" />
                            <p:ajax event="change" immediate="true" update="model model_ti"></p:ajax>
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Model">
                <p:cellEditor rendered="#{car.brand != 'Other'}">
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.model}" style="width:100%"
                            id="model">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{dtEditView.getModels(car.brand)}"
                                var="man" itemLabel="#{man}" itemValue="#{man}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
                <p:cellEditor rendered="#{car.brand == 'Other'}">
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">

                        <h:inputText value="#{car.model}" style="width:100%"
                            id="model_ti" />

                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by putting an ID on the cell editor for model, and adding that to the update list when changing brand.

Comment: Great you solved it, but explicit code examples help other more if they run into the same issue. Cheers!